# What is truncated data and how do I open my file that has it?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, decoding, xlrd

I am currently developing an ETL script that starts with pulling in data from an .xls file that we get from a third party. Unfortunately, this is the only viable format we can get the data in, so I need to be able to open this file. I can open it just fine in Microsoft Excel with no errors or warnings. When I try to open it using xlrd or pandas, I get the following error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x20 in position 108: truncated data`

I've been able to figure out that there is probably some kind of compression going on, but what little discussion I've been able to find on the issue is pretty arcane and beyond my knowledge. So, what does it mean that there is truncated data? What exactly is going wrong here? And most importantly, is there any way I actually can open this up without doing so manually?

**Current Process**

I can include additional code if necessary, but I'll just outline the process and put the code for the place where it seems like the tool is failing.

1. Using the exchangelib library, I access an email account and save the attachments if it has the subject line we're expecting. Right now, this is an .xls file we get from a third party. We're able to grab the attachment without issue.
2. I use the following function to write the file to the specified location. `attachment` is a list of components from the email/attachment. The element indexed with `3` in the function is the name, `4` is the attachment content. It's able to save the file and I'm able to open it without problem if I try it manually.

```
def write_file(download_folder, attachment):
    fpath = os.path.join(download_folder, attachment[3])
    with open(fpath, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(attachment[4])
```

3. I tried to open up the file with `pandas.read_excel()`, I get the error that I specified above. I was able to manually save the file as a .csv and it opened just fine with `pandas.read_csv()`. So, I tweaked a function I found on here that saves an .xls file as a .csv so that the process could still be automated. The function below is where I get an identical error.

```
def convert_to_csv(read_folder,read_name,write_folder=None,write_name=None,sheet_name="Sheet1"):
    if write_folder == None:
        write_folder = read_folder
    if write_name == None:
        write_name = read_name.replace("xls","csv")
    read_path = os.path.join(read_folder, read_name)
    write_path = os.path.join(write_folder, write_name)
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(read_path) #<----- This is where the error occurs
    ...

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x20 in position 108: truncated data
```

What is going on and is there any workaround I can use?

Comment: Would `pandas.read_excel()` work if you save an attachment _by hand_?

Comment: Negative. I get the same results for both that and ```convert_to_csv``` that's shown above.

Comment: One detail that I should add, if I open it manually *and* select Enable editing, it works. I just can't rely on doing that for an automated solution.

Comment: Can Excel open the file saved using the `write_file()` procedure? And what about `pandas.read_excel(open('read_path','rb'))`?

Comment: It can open that way and I just tried the second method and it's failing. The only commonality I've been able to find is that both methods are able to work once I've manually opened the document. I'm not sure what effect that has, but whatever change happens eliminates the decoding issue.